# Angular : how to set a conditional clear button for a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

within my Angular app

i ve a form containing a textarea

My prpose is to add a clear button inside the textarea elemnt , that clear button :

- should appear only when the texarea is focused
- should diseppear when the textarea is out of focus (click outisde)
- should clear the text written inside the textarea when clicked

i ve done this :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <p>This is a reactive form<br />
        <textarea (focusin)="componentMethod($event)" (focusout)="onfocusout($event)" formControlName="test" #test ></textarea>
        <button  *ngIf="showNotes" type="reset" id="close-resetNotes" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="resetNotes()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
    </p>
</form>
```

and in ts part :

```
export class AppComponent {
  public form: FormGroup;
  showNotes = false;
  @ViewChild("test") textareaElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      test: ["some text", Validators.nullValidator]
    });
  }

  public componentMethod(event) {
    this.showNotes = true;
  }

  public onfocusout(event) {
    this.showNotes = false;
  }

  resetNotes() {
    this.form.patchValue({ test: "" });
    this.showNotes = true;
  }
}
```

The problem with this , is that when click on clear button , the textarea get focused out even before appliying the onClick clear button actions

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: what is the problem here? If you click some other element, the current focus will change. That should be OK. Still, your click handler should be called. Isn't it?

Comment: Don t think that setimeout is a good alternative .. there is no better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `focus` and `blur` events of textarea and a variable to set conditions accordingly.
I have created a sample code based on your requirement, have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssmwxj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)